# Desabilitar modal do bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou tentando desabilitar um modal do bootstrap.

Eu preciso que ele inicie por padrão na página desabilitado, não chamando o modal do bootstrap, logo em seguida ser ativada ao selecionar um option.

Bem, eu já tentei algumas alternativas que não deram certo.

Primeiro tentei fazer com a função `unbind();`

```
$('.disabled-link').unbind();
```

A ideia era tentar tirar a função do click do link, não deu certo, pois continua aparecendo o modal.

Uma outra alternativa que pensei, foi tirar tirar o data-target="termosContrato" e depois recoloca-lo com `attr`

```
$("#dtTarget").attr('target', '#termosContrato');
```

Segue meu código da div que chama o modal

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="md-checkbox-list has-feedback" id="divTermosContrato">
        <div class="md-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkTermosContrato" name="chkTermosContrato" value="1" class="md-check" disabled="disabled">
          <label for="chkTermosContrato">
             <span></span>
             <span class="check"></span>
             <span class="box"></span> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termosContrato" id="dtTarget" class="disabled-link">Aceito os termos</a> </label>

        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="erroTermos help-block"> </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi mudar de:

```
$("#dtTarget").attr('target', '#termosContrato');
```

para:

```
$("#dtTarget").attr('data-target', '#termosContrato');
```

Comment: Se esta foi a resposta, aceite sua resposta e marque-a clicando no V logo abaixo da área dos votos e não escreva resolvido

Answer (score 0):

Para manipular os atributos com o prefixo `data` usando jQuery é recomendável usar a função `data` exemplo:

Pegar o `data-target` :

```
let target = $( '#dtTarget' ).data( 'target' );
```

Mudar o `data-target` :

```
$( '#dtTarget' ).data( 'target', '#termosContrato' );
```

Comment: Não é necessário chamar a pessoa, ela é notificada assim que você responde.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis, eu sei, mas é por conta de referenciação a resposta dele, e não a pergunta ^^